# How do I get has_and_belongs_to_many to do a bulk insert?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have two classes with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :segments

  def rematch_segments
    self.segments = Segment.customer_segments(self)
  end
end

class Segment < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :customers

  class << self
    def customer_segments(customer)
      ...returns a collection of Segments...
    end
  end
end
```

Calling `rematch_segments` results in an insert for each segment.

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
Customer::HABTM_Segments Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "customers_segments" ("customer_id", "segment_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)  [["customer_id", 1], ["segment_id", 1], ["created_at", "2020-03-24 23:42:52.985400"], ["updated_at", "2020-03-24 23:42:52.985400"]]
Customer::HABTM_Segments Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "customers_segments" ("customer_id", "segment_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)  [["customer_id", 1], ["segment_id", 2], ["created_at", "2020-03-24 23:42:52.987537"], ["updated_at", "2020-03-24 23:42:52.987537"]]
Customer::HABTM_Segments Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "customers_segments" ("customer_id", "segment_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)  [["customer_id", 1], ["segment_id", 3], ["created_at", "2020-03-24 23:42:52.988610"], ["updated_at", "2020-03-24 23:42:52.988610"]]
(0.3ms)  COMMIT
```

How can I instead do a single bulk insert?

Answer (score 4):

You can make the association visible by creating a class for your join table:

```rb
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :segments, through: :customer_segments
  has_many :customer_segments
end

class Segment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :customers, through: :customer_segments
  has_many :customer_segments
end

class CustomerSegment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :segment
end
```

This way you can use Rails 6's `insert_all()` (or the `activerecord-import` gem) to bulk insert the join table directly:

```rb
CustomerSegment.insert_all([
  { customer_id: 1, segment_id: 1 },
  { customer_id: 1, segment_id: 2 },
  …
])
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails 6 now supports bulk insert feature which can be used to insert multiple records in database in a single query. There is a [`insert_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all) method which accepts an array of hash representing each row to be inserted in the database. By default it skips duplicate rows

> Inserts multiple records into the database in a single SQL INSERT statement. It does not instantiate any models nor does it trigger Active Record callbacks or validations. Though passed values go through Active Record's type casting and serialization.
>
> The attributes parameter is an Array of Hashes. Every Hash determines the attributes for a single row and must have the same keys.
>
> Rows are considered to be unique by every unique index on the table. Any duplicate rows are skipped. Override with :unique_by (see below).

Assuming you've a `CustomerSegment` class representing your join model.

You can do something like this:

```
CustomerSegment.insert_all([{ customer_id: 54, segment_id: 2 },{ customer_id: 143, segment_id: 222 }...])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can use it to optimize the hotspot. You'd get the bounty, but Sunny answered just a few minutes before you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are focusing on performance, I would recommend using raw SQL rather than ORM which can have performance drawbacks relatively.

To simplify code, ['created_at', 'updated_at'] were removed.

#### 1. Using raw query

You may consider building INSERT QUERY like the following.

```
INSERT INTO customers_segments (customer_id,segment_id) VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,3) ...
```

According to records size, you may need to set batch size. Usually, it should be fine to
manage thousands records without batch size.

```
segments = Segment.find_by_attr(:attr_val) #please do not forget indexing of the attr in DB.
customer = Customer.create
stmt = segments.map {|seg| "(#{customer.id},#{seg.id})"}.join(",")

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO customers_segments (customer_id, segment_id) VALUES #{stmt}")
```

#### 2. implement raw query with ORM

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  def batch_rematch(attr_array)
    attr_val = attr_array.map{|a| %Q{'#{a}'} }.uniq.join(",")
    self.connection.execute(%Q{insert into customers_segments (customer_id,segment_id) 
                     select distinct customers.id,segments.id 
                     from customers,segments
                     where customers.id = #{self.id} 
                     and segments.<attr> in (#{attr_val})})
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I could do this by hand, but I'd prefer to let the ORM do it. The ORM should be able to do it as efficiently as I can. Note that Rails 6 introduced [`insert_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all) which does bulk inserts efficiently. For prior versions there is [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import).

Comment: @Schwern, yes, I have read insert_all doc before, but it does not explain much for relationship use case. It said "It does not instantiate any models nor does it trigger Active Record callbacks or validations.".

Comment: If one makes a model for the join table, then one should be able to `CustomerSegment.insert_all([{ customer: customer, segment: segment }, ...])` avoiding writing raw SQL. I might do that to optimize this particular method.